# Is Boltzmann's H the information or the negative of information?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

I noticed that Boltzmann's H is defined as

$$H_\mathrm{Boltzmann} = +\left<\ln p\right>$$

(where brackets indicate the expectation value) while the usual definition of

$$H_\mathrm{Information} = -\left<\ln p\right>$$

However, Boltmann's H theorem says that $H_\mathrm{Boltzmann}$ decreases over time. Naively, comparing the two equations, we are tempted to conclude that $H_\mathrm{Information}$ increases over time, which doesn't seem to make sense. What is the logical fallacy in this, and what is the reason for the sign difference? Additionally, why is $H_\mathrm{Boltzmann}$ often referred to as the information, rather than the negative of the information?